# Interpreting the output of image in open cv?

Tags: python, opencv

I just started open cv and I'm trying to understand the output that I'm getting from imread function. This is the code:

```
img = cv2.imread('...')
```

The image width x height is 3744 X 2104

But in the `img` variable I have defined, I have a multi dimensional array with shape (2104, 3744, 3).

I would like to know what does this shape mean in terms of images.

When I iterate over img, each item has a shape (3744, 3) and there 2104 such values. What I want to know is why do we have 3 x 3744 values 2104 times. I expected a matrix of width x height I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

the image has size 2104 pixels by 3744 pixels, the "3" is presumably the number of color channels, i.e. red green and blue